# Opening a php file in eclipse from windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, file-extension

I have changed my .php file extension association in windows to use eclipse to open .php files.  When I double-click a php file, it opens just fine as long as eclipse is not already open.  If eclipse is already open it tries to open ANOTHER one.  None of my other programs (UltraEdit, Winzip, etc) are retarded like this.

How do I get eclipse to just open the file in the already open workspace, without trying to re-launch a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the [oldest bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4922) in Eclipse.  Eclipse doesn't currently do this, though I'm sure there are products based on it that do.

The good news is that this is currently being worked on and should be available in 3.6.

See also the [swt](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201154) and [launcher](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=178927) bugs.